# Graph of the Hilbert transform of a function extended on Boehmians

Tags: integral-transforms

If a function is defined on set of Reals, we can draw the graph of function on plane, similarly we can draw the graph of its Hilbert transform. Now when we extend Hilbert transform to the space of Boehmians (or space of generalised functions). Can we draw the graph of Hilbert transform of a function on Boehmians?